# Get time zone name from Host OS Database Server

Tags: oracle, timezone

I've been struggle to get a time zone name dynamically at run-time from Oracle Host OS Server. What I mean by this is that I have no problem getting the offset, but not the name of the time zone:

```
select to_char(systimestamp, 'tzr') from dual;
```

or getting a list of timezone and its offset:

```
select * from V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
```

I'd imagine Oracle has to store this somewhere? I just can't find it...

Any help or pointer is appreciative.

Comment: You can also `select dbtimezone from dual;`, which [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions048.htm) say can return a region name; but both that and `tzr` show `+00:00` on my (UK) server, and `tzd` is null. (It knows it needs to change the clock to summer time next Sunday; though I guess it just gets that from the system clock? The DB time zone [is only used for `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#insertedID8)).

Comment: I've tried that Alex, i got the same result as you: "+00:00".

Comment: Well, that is what they recommend (from the same note at that link). If it relies on the system clock then I suppose it doesn't really need to know what the host OS time zone is. The session time zone is more useful, perhaps.

Comment: Actually DBTIMEZONE is the time zone set for the database server software on the server (which defaults to UTC or '+00:00' unless changed manually.) The OS itself might be in, say JST time, but unless your Oracle installation was told to mirror that, it will be in UTC by default (and that's why you see DBTIMEZONE returning 00:00)